# Waiting for a button state to change in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am testing a textbox and button - the user types in some information to the textbox and then hits the button - the button changes text from "Update" to "Updating" and then back to "Update" once the operation is complete.

I want Selenium to wait until the button returns back to "Update" before continuing.

I have tried various solutions using xpath here is where I am now:

```
self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, '//button[@id="send_data"][text()="Update"]'))
```

The HTML of the button is as follows:

```
<button id="send_data" type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="ChangeParam(this,'radio','freq'; return false;">Update</button>
```

and

```
<button id="send_data" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="ChangeParam(this,'radio','freq'; return false;">Updating</button>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite common issue: you should send `type_of_locator, "locator_string"` as tuple of arguments `((By.XPATH, "//button"))`, but not as two separate args `(By.XPATH, "//button")`

Use following code

```
self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@id="send_data"][text()="Update"]')))
```

Comment: Thanks, Selenium is now waiting but it doesn't appear to be waiting correctly as it runs the complete default 10 seconds whilst the button returns to "Update" after about 0.3 seconds.

Comment: Did you get `TimeOutException`? Also show what is `wait`

Comment: Wait is defined in my setUpClass class method as     ` cls.wait = WebDriverWait(cls.driver, 10) `

Comment: And yes, I get a TimeOutException. "raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: It means, that `webdriver` was unable to find clickable element within 10 seconds.. Check whether your radio-button located inside `iframe`/`frame`

Comment: Sorry, it's a regular button - and it's not inside an iframe / frame.

Comment: If to replace `element_to_be_clickable` with `presence_of_element_located`, same exception?

Comment: Yes, same exception. This button has a unique ID (send_data), is there a way to just locate the element by this ID and THEN check the text to wait for it to change? Rather than the current method I am using?

Comment: I think I've solved the problem using EC.text_to_be_present_in_element. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution that should work is using `EC.invisibility_of_element_located`. After clicking Update button, you can wait invisibility of Element which represented of "Updating" state button.

```
self.wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'button#send_data .btn-default')))
```